# Why is Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.9.0) not being consistent when trying to see the .cpp file in a cmake project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Edit: After making a new class today, I realized that some of VS's Intellisense doesn't take using aliases into account when trying to see definitions. After making a new class, creating definitions does work. Editing those definitions with a using alias afterwards for the namespace will trip Intellisense up and no longer see the connection between said definition and its declaration.

This results in the header file producing green squiggles under the declaration while at the same time the `Edit.GoToDefinition` command still works.

Workaround: Don't use an alias for function definitions.

---

I've made a small C++ project with CMake (first time touching CMake or C++ in years) in Visual Studio 2022 on Windows. Everything compiles and runs as I'd expect but the editor isn't acting how I'd expect it to. I think I'm missing something. Note: I plan to add more small projects to this in both C# and C++.

Current folder structure (I intend to make everything in C# and C++):

```
E:.
│   .gitignore
│   Algorithms.sln <- For the C# projects.
│   CMakeLists.txt <- For the C++ projects.
│   CMakePresets.json
│   LICENSE
│   README.md
│
└───DeltaTime <- The project. I expect to add more at this level later.
    ├───C# <- Just a C# version of what I'm trying to make with C++ below.
    └───C++
        │   CMakeLists.txt <- Defines this project.
        │
        ├───DeltaTime
        │       CMakeLists.txt <- Makes this a library.
        │       Ticker.cpp
        │       Ticker.hpp
        │
        ├───examples
        │       CMakeLists.txt <- Makes these executables. There may be more.
        │       main.cpp
        │
        └───Timepiece
                CMakeLists.txt <- Makes this a library.
                Stopwatch.cpp
                Stopwatch.hpp
```

Root CMakeLists.txt (everything above the project call was created by Visual Studio)

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8) 

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
# I broke this up to make sense of it.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(is_msvc $<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>)
  set(debug $<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>)
  set(format $<IF:${is_msvc},$<${debug}:EditAndContinue>,$<${debug}:ProgramDatabase>>)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT ${format})
endif()

project (Algorithms)

# This is just a dummy library to be applied to other libraries.
add_library(cxx_setup INTERFACE)
target_compile_options(cxx_setup INTERFACE -Wall)
if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    target_compile_options(cxx_setup INTERFACE -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()
target_compile_features(cxx_setup INTERFACE cxx_std_20)

if (ENABLE_BUILD_TESTING)
    enable_testing()
endif()

add_subdirectory (DeltaTime/C++)
```

DeltaTime/C++/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(DeltaTime)

add_subdirectory(Timepiece)
add_subdirectory(DeltaTime)
add_subdirectory(examples)

# I don't have this setup yet.
if(ENABLE_BUILD_TESTING)
    set(TESTS "")
    #target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${TESTS})
endif()
```

C++/Timepiece/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(Timepiece STATIC Stopwatch.cpp Stopwatch.hpp)
target_link_libraries(Timepiece PUBLIC cxx_setup)
target_include_directories(Timepiece PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

C++/DeltaTime/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(DeltaTime STATIC Ticker.cpp Ticker.hpp)
target_link_libraries(DeltaTime PRIVATE Timepiece)
target_include_directories(DeltaTime PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

C++/examples/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(BasicTicker main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(BasicTicker PRIVATE DeltaTime)
target_include_directories(BasicTicker PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

# This was generated by Visual Studio.
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET BasicTicker PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()
```

As I said, everything compiles and runs. However, there's some strange things going on with the editor.

[image: Screenshot showing green squiggles even though Edit.GoToDefinition command jumps over to the definition.]

All of the green squiggles you see are the exact same "problem". As you can see, the `Start` function doesn't have this problem. I'm also using the VsVim extension and mapped in normal mode `gi` to the `Edit.GoToDefinition` command. Invoking this, the cursor properly hops over to the definition.

[image: Visual Studio fails to generate definition in source file.]

Trying to use the action `Create definition of 'function' in STOPWATCH.CPP` from the `Show potential fixes` results in the image above. You can see it's trying to find this .cpp file in the wrong location.

Did I miss something in my CMakeLists that could fix these squiggles?
Is the way I've structured the files incorrect for how Visual Studio expects?

Comment: All of the green squiggles are IntelliSense false errors. If your code compiles, ignore the squiggles.

Comment: @273K I can understand that but the more annoying thing is the inability for VS to auto generate the definitions for me even though the very related command works! I had to manually type what you see myself.

Comment: Try to close VS and delete the directory .vs

Comment: I didn't think to delete the `.vs` folder. The `Start` function now has squiggles the `Create definition` action doesn't show that error anymore but it also still doesn't generate a definition. The green squiggles go away until I save any change in the .cpp file.